# Example when equality holds in Bessel Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

Example of $x\in l^2$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\leq \|x\|^2$ has strict inequality where $(e_k)$ is an orthonormal sequence in $l^2$.

My thinking: I think it's not possible
As $\|x\|\ _{2}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^2\right)^{1/2}$ and so by Bessel inequality we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\leq \left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\right)^2
$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^2\right)$$
But aren't both the things same, I mean there should be an equality

Kreyzig: Introduction to Functional Analysis, Ch-3, 3.4 Ques 4

Comment: Have you seen Parseval's theorem? It simply says that equality holds for all $x$ if and only if $(e_k)$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I got it, sir, if I take any orthonormal sequence which is not a basis, I will get a strict inequality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the confusion here is that the orthonormal sequence does not necessarily need to be a *complete* orthonormal sequence. (In other words, the closure of the span of $\{e_k \}$ need not be the whole of $l^2$.)

For example, consider the sequence
$$e_1 = (0,1,0,0,0\dots), \ \  \ e_2 = (0,0,1,0,0\dots), \ \ \ e_3 = (0,0,0,1,0\dots), \ \  \ \dots$$
which is orthonormal, but NOT complete.

Then consider $$x = (1,0,0,0,\dots).$$
You have $\langle x, e_i \rangle = 0$ for all $i$, so $\sum_i |\langle x, e_i \rangle |^2 = 0$. And yet, $|| x ||^2 = 1$.